# Which dll I need to include for AzureActiveDirectoryLoginProvider and AzureActiveDirectoryExtendedLoginProvider

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to following Microsoft Azure tutorial.

After I add these lines in my C# project,
    options.LoginProviders.Remove(typeof(AzureActiveDirectoryLoginProvider));
    options.LoginProviders.Add(typeof(AzureActiveDirectoryExtendedLoginProvider));

I get these Compiler errors:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'AzureActiveDirectoryLoginProvider'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\Users\SACHEU\Src\classified-prototype_\classified_prototypeService\App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs 19  50  classified_prototypeService

I have added 'using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.Security;' in the same file.
And I have added Microsofot.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service as my References. So can you please tell em what am I missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Tutorial](http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-users/):

```
Install the WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security NuGet package:

PM> Install-Package WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend.Security -Version 1.0.342-beta -Pre
```

The AzureActiveDirectoryLoginProvider is included in that package.